# How to allow lists to be entered as arguments Scheme

Tags: list, arguments, scheme, racket

I've been trying to write a procedure called shorter that accepts two arguments that are both lists.  Can I just use 'x' and 'y' to denote that lists would be entered there as arguments?  I've already written out the procedure and I don't see any errors with it, but when I attempt to run it, the interaction panel says "application: not a procedure; expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
given: 2
arguments...:

3"
and I don't quite know how to interpret this.  The procedure that I'm writing is below.

```
(define (shorter x y)
  (if ((length x) < (length y)) 
      x 
      (if ((length x) > (length y)) 
          y 
          x)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Racket is a prefix language, meaning that operators should come before arguments. How about:

```
(define (shorter x y)
  (if (< (length x) (length y))
      x 
      (if (> (length x) (length y)) 
          y 
          x)))
```

or...

```
(define (shorter x y)
  (if (<= (length x) (length y))
      x
      y))
```